# scp transfer with travis-ci

Tags: ssh, travis-ci, digital-ocean, sshd

trying to deploy to Digital Ocean from travis, keep getting

```
fatal: Unable to negotiate with 52.54.31.11 port 39748: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss [preauth]
```

on the host.

Tried adding lots of things to the .travis.yml most recently

```
before_script:
  - echo -e "Host 159.203.162.79\n\tUser root\n\tIdentityFile /tmp/deploy_rsa\n\tHostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
```

But no love. that just gets me

`/home/travis/.ssh/config line 7: Bad protocol 2 host key algorithms '+ssh-dss'.`

So, seems like an issue with a shiny new openssl, and travis being an old version?

I'm using a private key of course, that all seems to be working fine.

```
before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_ca03cb1712d9_key -iv $encrypted_ca03cb1712d9_iv -in deploy_rsa.enc -out /tmp/deploy_rsa -d && chmod 600 /tmp/deploy_rsa

before_deploy:
  - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
  - ssh-add /tmp/deploy_rsa
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite possibly. I can't list the supported key types on Precise image (because it is too old and does not support the `-Q` flag).

However, I have confirmed that the Trusty image does indeed support `ssh-dss` key. And this is enabled by default. I don't have a server to test with, but you should be able to move forward with:

```
dist: trusty
```

See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/trusty/ for more info.

Comment: seems that was it.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as the OP but adding dist: trusty did not resolve it.

Comment: @SethStone Do you have a build log URL to share? If it is the same problem, `dist: trusty` should fix it. If `dist: trusty` doesn't, then yours is most likely a different problem.

Comment: Well I've been through the trenches since my last comment.  Looking at the OP's post it would imply that the Travis host _is_ offering ssh-dss and the digital ocean server doesn't have it enabled.  What's misleading is that the "ssh_known_hosts" addon in Travis runs ssh-keyscan which attempts to "preauth" the server to see what keys and key types are available.  During this process it attempts DSS which is where that message is coming from, but it doesn't mean anything is wrong.  [ My actual issue was much less sophisticated, I had simply left off the "-d" flag to my openssl command.  :-| ]